# Entity Framework 5 Foreign Key New Record on SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using .NET4.5/EF5 and have created the model from an existing database.

I'm using the following code:

```
Order currentOrder = new Order();
using (var db = new ILSEntities())
{
    try
    {
        Event currentEvent = db.Events.OrderByDescending(u => u.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
        currentOrder.Event = currentEvent;
        db.Orders.Add(currentOrder);

        db.SaveChanges();
```

And I'm seeing that a duplicate record is being created of the Event object I find, which is not what I wanted to happen.

I've read a lot of posts relating to similar problems, but where the context of the two participants in the foreign key relationships are different. Here, I'm saving with the same context I use to find one, and the other object is new.

I've also tried:

```
currentOrder.Event.EventID = currentEvent.EventID;
```

but that fails as well as I get an EF validation error telling me it needs values for the other members of the Event object.

I've also tried specifically setting the `EntityState` of the object being duplicated to `Detached`, `Modified` etc. after adding the `Order` object but before `SaveChanges` without success.

I'm sure this is a basic problem, but it's got me baffled

Comment: Try to call `currentOrder.Event = currentEvent;` after the `db.Orders.Add(currentOrder);` line.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately, that didn't work either

Comment: Is that the *exact* code your are using? What you show cannot create a new `Event` because when you load the event it is attached to the context with state `Unchanged`.

Comment: With the exception of setting properties on the Order object, it IS the exact code

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding, both parent and child objects have to be in the context before you assign any relationship between them to convince the entity framework that an entity exists in the database already. I guess you are trying to add new Order object to Database, to add new object you should be using AddObject method, Add() method is used to establish relation between entitties.  In your code, `currentOrder` is not in the context. Try to hook it in the same context and then assign a relation. Your code should look like this :

```
Order currentOrder = new Order();
using (var db = new ILSEntities())
{
    try
    {
        Event currentEvent = db.Events.OrderByDescending(u => u.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
        db.Orders.Attach(currentOrder); //attach currentOrder to context as it was not loaded from the context
        currentOrder.Events.Add(currentEvent);//establish relationship

       db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(currentOrder, EntityState.Added);

        db.SaveChanges(); 
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ILSEntities has no ObjectStateManager

Answer (score 2):

OK, I did in the end figure this out, and it was my fault.

The problem was that the Order object is FK'd into another table, Shipments, which is also FK'd  into Events. The problem was that it was the Event reference in the Shipment object that was causing the new record. The solution was to let EF know about these relationships by adding them all within the same context.

The code assembling the object graph was spread over a number of webforms and the responses here made me take a step back and look at the whole thing critically so whilst no one of these answers is correct, I'm voting everybody who replied up